# How to from array want to form a pattern to make a query to make API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, api, axios

I want to derive a pattern from an array. The Array could be `n` number of elements

This is the Array pattern I receive from DB, (Note here elements could be `n` numbers)

```
[
  { id: '2', name: 'ONe' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Twop' },
  { id: '1', name: 'ThreeC' }
]
```

And I want to for a patter like `AccountId=2&AccountId=3&AccountId=1` formed from the array and `id` in it

And I want to pass that formed data into the below URL as a query parameter to make an API call.

```
 const config = {
          method: 'get',
          url: `${URL}api/cost?AccountId=1&AccountId=2&AccountId=3`,
          headers: {
            'Cookie': 'ARRAffinity=6f6eb54d3b6d7ed13173b9203b0bd6571b611d626818fba77a815805a7c90146'
          },
          data: data
        };
        const dataOutput = await axios(config )
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Does `AccountId`  equivalent to `name` key

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
stackOverflow = () => {
    let requestPartStr = '';
    const data = [
        { id: '2', name: 'ONe' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Twop' },
        { id: '1', name: 'ThreeC' }
    ];
    data.forEach((val, index) => {
        requestPartStr += index !== data.length - 1 
            ? `AccountId=${val.id}&` 
            : `AccountId=${val.id}`;
    })

    return requestPartStr;
};
```

Based on given code this can be a full code example:

```
const data = [
    { id: '2', name: 'ONe' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Twop' },
    { id: '1', name: 'ThreeC' }
];

getRequestParameters = (data) => {
    let requestPartStr = '';
    
    data.forEach((val, index) => {
        requestPartStr += index !== data.length - 1
            ? `AccountId=${val.id}&`
            : `AccountId=${val.id}`;
    })

    return requestPartStr;
};

const requestParameters = getRequestParameters(data);
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `${URL}api/cost?${requestParameters}`,
    headers: {
        'Cookie': 'ARRAffinity=6f6eb54d3b6d7ed13173b9203b0bd6571b611d626818fba77a815805a7c90146'
    },
    data: data
};
const dataOutput = await axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    return response.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: maybe a ```data.map(o=>`AccountId=${o.id}`).join('&');``` if you feel like trading typing effort for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `join` to build a params string

```js
const data = [
  { id: "2", name: "ONe" },
  { id: "3", name: "Twop" },
  { id: "1", name: "ThreeC" },
];

const params = data.map(({ id }) => `AccountId=${id}`).join("&");
const url = `foo.com/api/cost?${params}`;

console.log(url);
```